# How to get nested JSON in android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get values from nested JSON Array but getting Null.
This my java code :

```
                           JSONObject root = new JSONObject(items);
                           JSONArray arr = root.getJSONArray("product");
                           for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                           {
                             JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                             path = "" + obj.optString("image");
                             al_prod_id.add("" + obj.optString("product_id"));
                             al_prod_name.add("" + obj.optString("product_name"));
                             al_prod_price.add(""+ obj.optString("price"));
                             al_prod_image.add(""+imagebase+path);
                             }

                        setupProductforMall();
```

This is my JSON :

```
               {
                 "status": "success",
                 "data": {
                       "flashsale_id": "1",
                       "flashsale_name": "New Summer Sale",
                       "flashsale_image": "aa.jpg",
                       "flashsale_product": "8,11,12",
                       "discount": "20",
                       "st_time": "10/05/2017  10:25:59",
                       "ed_time": "30/05/2017  10:25:59",
                        "product": [
                                     {
                                       "0": {
                                              "product_id": "8",
                                           "product_name": "Prottin Shake",
                                              "price": "799/-",
                                              "stock": "100",
                                              "description": "This is 
                                               strongest drink that gives 
                                               you instant energy",
                                              "image": 
                                     "ea0fb7c33d9c025627fbb2f591e09083.png",
                                              "Discount": "30%",
                                              "Discount_on": "1",
                                              "Coupan_Code": "ADFG235"
                                             }
                                            },
                                       {
                                         "0": {
                                              "product_id": "11",
                                              "product_name": "GYM Product",
                                              "price": "7500",
                                              "stock": "15",
                                              "description": "Best Product",
                                              "image": 
                                     "be804ee59ccb0597f8ac2cd6e186954c.png",
                                             "Discount": "40%",
                                             "Discount_on": "2",
                                             "Coupan_Code": "BVC9988"
                                             }
                                            }
                                           ]
                                          },
                                        "message": "flashsale "
                                        }
```

How to fetch nested JSON? How to fetch 2 dimensional array in android? I have tried with nested for loop but still getting null array? Please help me to resolve, I am new at android.

Comment: `Jason` ??? it should be `Json`

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **JSONObject "0"** inside the JSONObjects of **product** **JSONArray**. You should Parse your JSON like this-

```
try{
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(items);
        JSONObject data = root.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray productArray = data.getJSONArray("product");
        for (int i=0; i<productArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject productObjects = productArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject productIndex = productObjects.getJSONObject("0");
            path = "" + productIndex.getString("image");
            al_prod_id.add("" + productIndex.getString("product_id"));
            al_prod_name.add("" + productIndex.getString("product_name"));
            al_prod_price.add(""+ productIndex.getString("price"));
            al_prod_image.add(""+imagebase+path);
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }
```

hope it will be helpful.. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need `getJSONObject` to get `JSONObject`, not by casting it.

Change this line:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
```

to this:

```
JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: Perfect answer .

Comment: @Abhijeet you need to do `obj.getJSONObject("0")` before you can get your image, product_id and etc.

Comment: And try to use `getString` instead of `optString`, and put the codes inside a Try-catch Exception block so you can know exactly which line is throwing Exception. Will save you quite some times.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to parse json is just create a pojo class with the help of [json to pojo website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

and if there are nesting in json then simply implement the Parcelable Interface to all pojo class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static Object getValue(JSONObject jsonObject, String key)
{
    if (jsonObject.has(key))
    {
        return jsonObject.get(key);
    }

    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Object value = jsonObject.get(iterator.next());
        if (value instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            return getValue((JSONObject) value, key);
        }
        else if (value instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((JSONArray) value).length(); i++)
            {
                return getValue(((JSONArray) value).getJSONObject(i), key);
            }
        }
    }
    return "not found";
}
```